# Is there an alternative for function Present in a UItableViewCell?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, navigation, xib

I want to navigate from UITableViewCell(Xib) to UIViewController but when I try to use present  `Value of type 'TableViewCell' has no member 'present` 
So if anyone is familiar with a function that can help me navigate please help me :) .

Thank you for your time

Comment: you can use tableview `didSelectRowAt`, and from that your controller (a.k.a self), has the "self.present...."

Comment: @GustavoVollbrecht yes it's a good idea but what if  inside the tableviewcell there's a button and we want that button to navigate us instead of the whole cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UITableViewCell can’t present viewcontroller. Please store viewController to variable in your tableview cell. And use it to present. 
Or use `didSelectRowAt` delegate function and using self to present ( Or write your custom cell delegate if your event fire by button in cell)

Answer (score 2):

Conform your `ViewController` to `UITableViewDelegate` protocol and then in your `ViewController` code use the delegate method: `func tableView(UITableView, didSelectRowAt: IndexPath)` and inside this method perform/present a segue or any other type of navigation you have.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }   

    func tableView(UITableView, didSelectRowAt: IndexPath) {
            // navigation logic here
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **`closure`** inside your custom `UITableViewCell` to handle this scenario.

In your custom  `UITableViewCell` create a `handler` and call it when the `button` is tapped inside the `cell`, i.e.

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    var handler: (()->())?

    @IBAction func onTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        handler?()
    }
}
```

Now, set the `handler` in `cellForRowAt` when creating the `cell`, i.e.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.handler = {
        //present your controller here...
    }
    return cell
}
```